# Why won't my small CSS Animation trigger?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

Other code that might be blocking the animation:

```
.projectLinks a{
  background-color: var(--secondary-color);
  color: var(--main-color);
  padding: 2px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
```

Animation

```
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .3s;
}

.projectLinks a:hover{
  background-color: var(--secondary-hover);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

The hover color is applied but there is no transition. Why is that?

Here is a link to a codepen recreation of what I have:

https://codepen.io/Ancross/pen/yLKabeM

Comment: Hard to say without a [mcve]

Comment: Fair enough. I added a codepen link that mimics what I have in my app

Comment: Sorry, the [mcve] needs to be in your question, not on a third-party site. There's a snippets feature in the editor that can do what codepen does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to change the display property of the links. By default they are display inline.

To keep a similar look, I used **display:inline**

```css
.projectLinks a{
  background-color: rgb(0, 153, 255);
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 4px 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  display:inline-block;
}

.projectLinks a:hover{
  background-color: rgb(1, 137, 228);
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
```

```html
<div class='projectLinks'>
  <a>Text</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using translateY on an inline-level element which can not be transformed due to some limitation. To use it correctly you can make it an `inline-block`

write this line in CSS like

```
.projectLinks a {
  ...
  display: inline-block;
}
```

this will cause this to display inline but as a block for more info about inline element and block level element please refer below MDN docs:

- inline elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements
- block level element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements